# Was Mjolnir ever used for building something?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, mjolnir, thor-2011

In the movie *Thor* (2011), while he was about to crown Thor as the next king of Asgard, Allfather Odin describes the mighty hammer Mjolnir as the following:

> So long entrusted with this mighty hammer, Mjolnir. Forged in the heart of a dying star, from the sacred metal of Uru. Only one may ift it. Only one is worthy. Who wields this hammer commands the lightning and the storm. Its power has no equal -- as a weapon, to destroy, **or as a tool, to build**. It is a fit companion for a King.

We know Mjolnir as a weapon of destruction but are there references where it is used to build something?

Comment: In the original mythos it's used to build a very large wall.

Comment: @Valorum The stories from Mythology, comics are also welcome. Actually, I was more interested in comics because movies haven't focussed on it much.

Comment: maybe build peace?

Comment: @Taladris - Does "Building *dramatic tension*" count, do you think?

Comment: I think it was more intended as a play on the fact that hammers are tools used to build things, and that Mjolnir, as it is a weapon that is a hammer, can be used for more than as a weapon. I believe that speech was meant to seem grandiose, and that the "as a weapon, to destroy, or as a tool, to build" part makes it sound like Odin is very wise and kind or gentle.

Comment: It's a hot question: https://youtu.be/-tt1HkiTcZ0?feature=shared&t=1127

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are certainly a few examples from the comics:

Thor uses Mjölnir to hammer a shaky pillar back into the ground in [*Thor* #267](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_267)

[image: Thor knocks the pillar into the ground in a blur of motion]

He uses his hammer to build a trench in [*Avengers* #98](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_98)

[image: Thor creates the trench by spinning the hammer really fast into the ground]

He also uses his hammer to build a lava channel in [*Marvel Team-Up* #26](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Team-Up_Vol_1_26)

[image: Thor creates the channel by repeatedly hitting the ground with the hammer]

Comment: I question whether these are building, or just a form of destruction not targeted at human beings. ;)

Comment: @Adamant - The ditch-digging is a bit debatable. Him hammering a pillar into the ground is undoubtedly a form of construction activity.

Answer (score 46):

## Vision.

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Thor uses Mjolnir to bring Vision to life.

It is a loose definition of "build" but I would consider this to be what Odin had in mind. Unfortunately, building is usually not as exciting as destruction, so it is less likely to be portrayed on screen in general.

Comment: ...except when you are building a Death Star. Then you build as many as possible!

Answer (score 40):

In the comic *Thor* #377 (March 1987, written by Walt Simonson), Thor uses Mjolnir to smith a new suit of protective armor.

[image: Builder Thor creates some new armor by using the hammer]

Comment: "The Mortal Metropolis of Pittsburgh!"

Comment: The Steel City, The City of Champions, I can see why the god of thunder would be attracted to such a place!

Answer (score 23):

It was used to rebuild Asgard.

In a comic from 2004, Asgard was destroyed. Then in a truly wonderful sequence from a comic in 2007, Thor rebuilt the city of Asgard in Oklahoma by waving Mjolnir around, striking a series of dramatic poses and shouting "Asgaaaaaard!"

[image: Thor building Asgard]

Comment: This sequence doesn't seem to show anything relevant

Comment: He's striking a dramatic pose and waving the hammer around in Oklahoma. This page is the start of the sequence in which he rebuilds Asgard. I could not find the full sequence online with English text.

Comment: Perhaps a scan of the actual city being assembled (and any accompanying narration or dialog explaining the process) would be more relevant.

Comment: "Thor rebuilt the city of Asgard in Oklahoma" - hey, that's a spoiler of the next Thor movie! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard except the comic misspelled Norway.

Answer (score 11):

## Trust

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, The Vision picks up Mjolnir to gain Thor and the Avengers' trust.

> The Vision: ...But there may be no way to make you trust me
> **picks up Mjolnir**
> The Vision: But we need to go
> **hands Mjolnir to Thor **

As a symbol of trust and 'let's focus on the *real* enemy', The Vision surprises the team with this action as it's sort of a running gag/plot-point that only the worthy (at the point only Thor himself) can carry Mjolnir. **He's using Mjolnir to build trust between himself and the Avengers.**

Comment: Could also add that in his actions Thor is actively building peace and security for the realms he protects. Not sure if I should stretch is so far though.

Answer (score 6):

In "The Truth of History" (2008), Thor and the Warriors Three find themselves way back in Ancient Egypt. Thor lends a hammer to help slaves cutting giant stones for a pyramid.

[image: Thor uses the hammer plus lightning to break the big stones]