# Has Mjolnir ever been used "as a tool to build"?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

In the MCU movie *Thor*, Odin says that Thor's hammer "has no equal as a weapon to destroy, or as a tool to build."

We see it used as a weapon plenty of times throughout the MCU's run, but I don't think I've ever seen it used as "a tool to build."  Has it ever been employed as a tool, in the movies or the comics?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I imagine that Thor could pound nails with it if he wanted to. In fact, it could probably knock in some pretty big nails to build a very large structure.

Comment: Yes, it has been used to build lots of things, [_Trust_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174009/21267) for example.